# how to set the row number of row for checkboxlist in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I have one checkboxlist with repeat columns=3. If the item count for the datasource of it is less than 20,i need to generate 20 rows with single column.If it is between 21 and 40 then 20 rows and two columns.if it is between 41 to 60 then 20 rows and 3 columns and for more than 60 records then as normal that checkboxlist behave.
  Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks
Mohak

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
int itemCount = <YOUR_DATASOURCE_ITEMS>.Count;
int columnCount = Math.Ceiling(itemCount/20.0)
<YOUR_CHECKBOX_LIST>.RepeatColumns = columnCount;
```